# Is there any program American can take advantage of to help offset childcare costs during Covid-19?

Tags: united-states, tax-deduction, tax-credit, child-care, new-mexico

Due to Covid-19, my son's schools have been shut down for most of the year. Though my workplace allows parents to bring their children to work, he is special needs/has a disability, so requires much assistance. As such, we've had to pay a babysitter to help him through the on-line classes, accounting for 1/4 of our weekly expenses.

I'm wondering if there are any programs I can apply for, such as some stimulus money for this purpose? Or is there something I can fill out while filing taxes in January to reduce taxes paid?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some employers have waived some open enrollment deadlines for applying for a Dependent Care Inflexible Savings Account (a "DC FSA").  This is implemented as a deduction from your income, that can be spent using pre-tax dollars.  For 2020 and 2021 the limit is $5000.

For more see https://www.investopedia.com/articles/pf/09/dependent-care-fsa.asp

If you still can, get on board for 2021, however keep in mind unspent dollars get donated to your company.

---

Look into the "Child and dependent care credit".
Note that age limits are waived, depending on the disability of the child.
And there are phaseouts depending on your income.

---

And note you can't stack these two credits quite as nicely as you might like.

---

Finally consider the "unreimbursed medical expense" deduction, available for expenses that exceed 7.5% of your income.  Generally, deductible medical expenses must be required by a doctor in writing, though you're probably fine getting the doctor's note now under the circumstances.

---

Congratulations you're also now an employer and may have a "Zoë Baird Problem" depending on how long this has gone on.  You are required to file forms **1099-ENT** to report the babysitter's income.  Watch out that deadline is February 1st 2021.